# Disable button on specific slide

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slide

i have make it an slider with 2 image, the first is Gotrade and second Midas. I want when im on first slide to not display the left arrow and when im on second  the right arrow to not be displayed.

```
 if (firstSlide.classList.contains('active-slide')) {
 buttonLeft.style.display = 'none';
 buttonRight.style.display = 'flex';
} else if (secondSlide.classList.contains('second-slide')) {
 buttonLeft.style.display = 'flex';
 buttonRight.style.display = 'none';
}
```

I tried this but doesn't work.
Here is the image for reference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTXdt.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/82clB.png

Codepen: https://codepen.io/andrei-nistor/pen/ZEeeGEG

Comment: This needs more debugging details - what are `buttonLeft` and `buttonRight`? Have you confirmed they're pointing to the right element? Same for `firstSlide` and `secondSlide` - and have you verified the classes are right? When does this code run - have you verified it runs after a slide transition? You can probably use `console.log` to inspect the code as it runs instead of asking StackOverflow

Comment: If i find it the solution really i not posted on stackoverflow. You have some image for reference where you see the buttonLeft and buttonRight how is the Arrow direction

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: @AndreiNistor Images don't tell us anything about the markup or when your code is running. There's not enough information here to answer your quesiton. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Andy Ray you know i can't copy a lot of lane of codes of html

Comment: https://codepen.io/andrei-nistor/pen/ZEeeGEG Here is the html css js

Comment: Your codepen example doesn't include the code from your question, can you add that to the codepen too?

Comment: Done, it was commented .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. For example, you're checking for a classname called `active-slide`, but nothing in your code sets a class with that name. If you're copying and pasting code from other sources without taking some time to understand it, it may be impossible to debug.

Instead of checking for the existence of a class that doesn't exist, you can instead check for which slide number you're on, and check if you're on the first or last slide. You also need to run this code after slide transitions, not once at the end of your program as you've shown in the Codepen. Here's an example of the working Javascript checking for `slideIndex` instead of a class:

```
var slideIndex = 1;

let firstSlide = document.querySelector('.first-slide');
let secondSlide = document.querySelector('.second-slide');
let buttonLeft = document.querySelector('.prev');
let buttonRight = document.querySelector('.next');

showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "flex";

    if (slideIndex === 1) {
        buttonLeft.style.display = 'none';
        buttonRight.style.display = 'flex';
    } else if (slideIndex === slides.length) {
        buttonRight.style.display = 'none';
        buttonLeft.style.display = 'flex';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it something with class 'active-slide'

Comment: It's difficult to answer questions if the code you're having trouble with is different than the code you post in the question. The more specific you can make your question with reproducible steps, the better and faster answers you'll get.